# We call this assumption [the] good function assumption

Tags: grammar, determiners

Should I put the "the" in this sentence?

We call this assumption [the] good function assumption hereafter.

Comment: Yes, but add quotes around "good function assumption" to make it clear you're renaming it.   *Hereafter we call this the "good function assumption".*

Comment: Thank you. Shouldn't "the" be in the quotation?

Comment: You can put "the" inside the quote.  There are various options, (including whether or not it should be capitalized):  *"The good function assumption", the "Good Function" assumption*, etc.  Which you use may depend on what is common practice within your academic field.   I suggest you find another published paper with a similar sentence and copy that style.

Comment: I would not put "the" inside the quotes.  Most alphabetical lists of movies and books ignore "The" at the beginning of a title and use the following word to sort within the list.  Imagine that you might later discuss the "Good Function Assumption" with someone and say something like, "This is an example of a Good Function Assumption".  See why you don't include the "the"?

Comment: Thank you all. And, is quotation preferable to making the text italic?

Comment: Italicizing is more professional and conveys the same meaning as using quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, but add quotes or italics around "good function assumption" to make it clear you're renaming it.

> Hereafter we call this the *good function assumption*.

It's a question of style whether or not to add "the" inside the quotes, or whether to capitalize the title.  With formal papers there is usually some kind of "style guide" that explains what is common and expected, but this varies between different publications and different schools.  The guide (or other papers in the subject) should help you decide whether it's better to use italics or quotes.

That being said, I agree with user6570789 and would write:

> the *good function* assumption

or

> the "good function" assumption

in order to distinguish it from other kinds of assumptions.

Note that if there can be more than one "flavor" of *good function* assumption, you should say *a* good function assumption, and not *the* good function assumption.